# How to pass Encoded Audio String to bytes with json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, encoding, python-requests

I have been trying to implement the below shell code with python.
I am about to make use of [deepaffects speaker identification api](https://docs.deepaffects.com/docs/speaker-enrollment-api.html) . So before its's use i need to enroll the audio file with user id , in their docs there is no python example given instead of below shell commands.

```
curl -X POST "https://proxy.api.deepaffects.com/audio/generic/api/v1    /sync/diarization/enroll?apikey=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" -H 'content-type: application/json' -d @data.json

# contents of data.json
{"content": "bytesEncodedAudioString", "sampleRate": 8000, "encoding":   "FLAC", "languageCode": "en-US", "speakerId": "user1" }
```

So far now I had written the below code.

```
 import requests

 url = 'https://proxy.api.deepaffects.com/audio/generic/api/v1   /sync/diarization/enroll?apikey=<3XY9aG7AbXZ4AuKyAip7SXfNNdc4mwq3>'

 data = {
     "content": "bytesEncodedAudioString", 
     "sampleRate": 8000, 
     "encoding": "FLAC",
     "languageCode": "en-US", 
     "speakerId": "Pranshu Ranjan",
  }

  headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
  r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers) 
  print(r)
```

But I don't know how to pass the `"content": "bytesEncodedAudioString"`. I have audio samples in mp3 format in my local directory.
here is the [deepAffects api reference](https://seernet.github.io/slate/?shell#speaker-enrollment-api) and they support multiple audio formats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.deepaffects.com/docs/speaker-enrollment-api.html#body-parameters):

> content   (String)    base64 encoding of the audio file.

Just use built-in `base64` module to encode your audio file:

```py
import base64
import requests


filepath = "C:\Audio\...\file.mp3"
with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    audio_encoded = base64.b64encode(f.read())  # read file into RAM and encode it

data = {
    "content": str(audio_encoded),  # base64 string
    "sampleRate": 8000, 
    "encoding": "FLAC",  # maybe "MP3" should be there?
    "languageCode": "en-US", 
    "speakerId": "My Name",
}

url = ...
r = requests.post(url, json=data)  # note json= here. Headers will be set automatically.
```

Comment: I tried with your above code ,but it throws the below error when i passed my audio file of mp3 format and also changed the encoding type in data. `TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: ahh! just a simple mistake , even i too forget that i have to pass the byte encoded string not the bytes itslef. Thanks a lot man, it now works!!!! @Ivan Vinogradov